# How to get the data from x document and upload it to a new document called 'name' and then delete the old one in java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to get the data from x document and upload it to a new document called 'name' and then delete the old one in java

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
// get the data from 'name@xxx.com'
firestore.collection("users").doc("name@xxx.com").get().then(function (doc) {
    if (doc && doc.exists) {
        var data = doc.data();
        // saves the data to 'name'
        firestore.collection("users").doc("name").set(data).then({
            // deletes the old document
            firestore.collection("users").doc("name@xxx.com").delete();
        });
    }
});
```

I've got this code snippet from a Bjorn Reemer but I am unable to get it working in android java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference ref = db.document("users/name@xxx.com");
DocumentReference destRef = db.document("users/name");
db.runTransaction((Transaction.Function<Void>) transaction -> {
    DocumentSnapshot document = transaction.get(ref);
    if (document.exists()) {
        transaction.set(destRef, document.getData());
        transaction.delete(ref);
    }
    return null;
});
```